# Sibling Selector Selecting child elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<p>hello
    <div>test</div>
</p>

<div>yo
    <p>hi</p>
</div>

<p>hello</p>
```

I have the following code and when I use the following styles I get the following.

```
p + div {
    color:orange;
}
```

[image]

It styles the div inside the p, and I thought that it's only supposed to style siblings immediately after on the same level? What's weird is if I do the following

```
div + p {
     color:orange;
}
```

it does not style the p inside the div tag as shown.

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: the p inside the div inherits the yellow of the parent div that you have styled in the first example, in the second example, you only have the last p that immediately follows a div which is why only that one is styled.  (as an aside, your div inside the p is invalid html)

Comment: @pete actually the aside explains the actual reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML markup is invalid. `<div>` cannot be placed inside `<p>` so the browser ***fixes*** the markup by changing this:

```
<p>hello
  <div>test</div>
</p>
<div>yo
  <p>hi</p>
</div>
<p>hello</p>
```

... into this:

```
<p>hello</p>
<div>test</div>
<p></p>
<div>yo
  <p>hi</p>
</div>
<p>hello</p>
```

Now `p + div` matches `test` and `yo`. And `hi` inherits the parent's color.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken when you put **div** inside **p** tag.

so **<div>test</div>** is considered as adjacent to **p** and applied orange color.

and **<div>yo<p>hi</p> </div>** is considered as adjacent to another **p** and applied orange color.

For more clarity, See the below DOM structure that has been created using above code.

[image]